# Bloom-release issue: could not resolve rosdep key 'rospkg'

Tags: ros, rosdep, rospkg, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

I have an anoying issue that I can't get solved...

To test debian building and releasing,  I created two repos on github. One for source and the other for the release debians.
I commited two of our nodes for testing purpose before trying to use our internal git and build in local instead of on the ros buildfarm...
So I try to take it small steps after small steps to try to control all the aspects...

So, I'm compiling perfectly well the packages with `catkin_make` and `catkin_make install` in 'devel' overlay.
The install folder can be relocated anywhere and executes the nodes smoothly when I update the bashrc to source the correct folder as overlay etc...

So all seems pretty clean to me.

I do run `catkin_generate_changelog` and `catkin_prepare_release` still in the 'devel' overlay.

BUT.
When running `bloom-release --rosdistro hydro --track hydro https://github.com/repo/repo.git --edit`  in the 'devel' overlay, I have the following error:

```
==> git-bloom-generate -y rosdebian --prefix release/hydro hydro -i 0
Generating source debs for the packages: ['deburring_riveting_demo', 'hironx_grippers']
Debian Incremental Version: 0
Debian Distributions: ['precise', 'quantal', 'raring']
Releasing for rosdistro: hydro
Placing debian template files into 'debian/hydro/deburring_riveting_demo' branch.
==> Placing templates files in the 'debian' folder.
Running 'rosdep update'...

####
#### Generating 'precise' debian for package 'deburring_riveting_demo' at version '0.0.2-0'
####
Generating debian for precise...
No homepage set, defaulting to ''
Could not resolve rosdep key 'rospkg'
Try to resolve the problem with rosdep and then continue.
```

So Yes, my python package 'deburring_riveting_demo' imports rospkg.
And in `package.xml` I added `<run_depend>python-rospkg</run_depend>` 
Also tried to add it also in <build_depend>, but didn't change anything...

So as discussed on some other questions, I did clean my rosdep files and updated them.
And I also run `rosdep resolve python-rospkg` correctly since it answers

```
#apt
python-rospkg
```

I have to mention that at the beginning I did try in `package.xml` to < -depend> on `rospkg` instead of `python-rospkg`.
That might be one of the origins of bloom trying to rosdep rospkg??

So I have no clue about how to solve this issue...

I'm guessing that there might have a cache somewhere still pointing to `<run_depend>rospkg</run_depend>`

But I deleted my /devel, /build and /install; I deleted all temporary files in /src, I double checked the correctness of the upstream git repo...

Is there anywhere else I have to look for this??

Any idea of what is going wrong?

Thanks
Damien

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193400/bloom-release-issue:-could-not-resolve-rosdep-key-%27rospkg%27/) by [Damien](https://answers.ros.org/users/2349/damien/) on ROS Answers with karma: 203 on 2014-09-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-09-24**:
I [had the same issue before](http://answers.ros.org/question/60271/could-not-resolve-rosdep-key-rospkg/). Double/Triple-check like this might help: `$ grep -r ">rospkg" $YOUR_CATKIN_WS$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

bloom operates on the released packages, so my guess is that you have not released since addressing this:

> I have to mention that at the beginning I did try in package.xml to < -depend> on rospkg instead of python-rospkg. That might be one of the origins of bloom trying to rosdep rospkg??

Make sure the released version (tag in git repository which matches the version you are releasing) has the correct dependency name in the `package.xml`.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-09-24**:
The tagged version does not have the updated dependency: https://github.com/Flexbotics/Flexbotics/blob/0.0.2/deburring_riveting_demo/package.xml

**Comment by [Damien](https://answers.ros.org/users/2349/damien/) on 2014-09-25**:
That was it!!
Too many steps and stuff to learn and control at the same time...
I didn't regenrate `catkin_prepare_release` Now it works smoothly.
Thanks a lot.
I'm closing the question.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-09-25**:
@Damien Thanks for confirming the answer and following up. For future reference, marking the answer as accepted is enough. If you close it others's can't comment or add additional suggestions or alternative solutions.